# How many constitutions refer to the Declaration of the Rights of Man?

Tags: law, constitution, history, human-rights, liberalism

I'm curious how many countries cite the document in their own constitution, as I'm aware that some do (Senegal, for example).

[Declaration of the Rights of Man and of the Citizen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_of_the_Rights_of_Man_and_of_the_Citizen)

Comment: What is the focal point here, the word "Man", or the spirit of the document?

Comment: @r13 why would you think the word "man" was at issue?

Comment: @phoog Without dig deeper into the background, my first impression was that declaration is of the rights to "MAN" only, which can be misleading.

Comment: @r13 but why would you think this question is about that?  There's nothing in the question to suggest it.

Comment: @phoog Yeah, let's see how the OP and others say. I've glanced through, maybe go deeper if the topic is heated up.

Comment: @phoog I am not clear on the question, so I ask through comment.

Comment: @phoog Similarly, I am not clear why you question my comment/question to the OP.

Comment: @r13 it seems to me that neither "the word 'man'" nor "the spirit of the document" is at issue here.  The question is only about constitutions explicitly mentioning the document, or not.  As asked, the question takes no account of the actual rights recognized in the constitution.  Consider a question such as "how many papers cite Einstein's theory of special relativity" and you asked whether the question was interested in time dilation or in the equivalence of non inertial frames of reference.  It is irrelevant.

Comment: @phoog Sorry, I don't get it. Let's stop the conversation here.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know - three. Due to Senegal's history as part of France's colonial holdings in West Africa, the country's constitution is based heavily on France's own:

> The French people solemnly proclaim their attachment to the Rights of
> Man and the principles  of  national  sovereignty  as  defined  by  the
> Declaration  of  1789,  confirmed and  complemented  by  the  Preamble
> to  the  Constitution  of  1946,  and  to  the  rights and duties as
> defined in the Charter for the Environment of 2004.

I believe the only other country to contain a reference to the 1789 document is Gabon, another country that used to form part of France's colonial empire:

> The Gabonese people, conscious of its responsibility before History,
> animated by the willingness to assure its independence and its
> national unity, to organize the common life according to the
> principles of national sovereignty, pluralist democracy, social
> justice, and republican legality;
>
> Solemnly affirms its adherence to the rights of man and the
> fundamental liberties such as they result from the Declaration of the
> Rights of Man and the Citizen of 1789 and the Universal Declaration of
> Human Rights of 1948, consecrated by the African Charter of the Rights
> of Man and the Rights of Peoples of 1981, and by the National Charter
> of Liberties of 1990;

Other countries with a similar history - such as those I reference in my answer to [this similar question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/40704/28994) - don't seem to have maintained this reference, choosing instead to refer to the 1948 Universal Declaration of the Rights of Man - for example, the Central African Republic:

> Reaffirms their adherence to the Charter of the Organization of the
> United Nations, to the Universal Declaration of the Rights of Man of
> 10 December 1948, to the International Pacts of 16 December 1966
> concerning economic, social and cultural right on the one hand and
> civil and political rights on the other;

and Côte d'Ivoire:

> Proclaims its adherence to the rights and freedoms as defined in the
> Universal Declaration of the Rights of Man of 1948 and in the African
> Charter of the Rights of Man and of Peoples of 1981;